# woven appearance of water-streams by the side of the street

Tags: fluid-dynamics

It's pretty rainy in Boston now, and there are streams of water by the sides of the street.

Why do they have a 'woven' appearance? What's the formal name for this kind of fluid flow? With lots of diagonals criss-crossing each other. And is there a good way to simulate it?

Answer (score 3):

A gravity-driven free surface flow on an incline is unstable at moderate Reynolds number, as was shown by Yih, 1963, http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/69956 : surface waves form. These waves are, I believe, also unstable in the transverse direction, leading to the criss-cross pattern you mention. See Liu et al 1995, http://scholarship.haverford.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1049&context=physics_facpubs

Shallow-water equations (i.e. Navier-Stokes reduced to the case of small depth) with gravity and some perturbation introduced by lateral BC e.g. should be enough to get a hint, 3D Navier-Stokes simulations would probably be necessary to capture the complete development of the pattern.